# What difference between these 2 SQL styles?

Tags: redshift

If I have a simple table named: conn_log in my Redshift/Postgresql

[image]

In the performance of view, what difference between these two commands ?

```
select t1.wifi_name, (t2.sconn*100)::numeric/t1.ttconn
from (select wifi_name, count(*) as ttconn 
      from conn_log 
      group by wifi_name) t1, 
     (select wifi_name, count(*) as sconn 
      from conn_log 
      where success = 1 
      group by wifi_name) t2
where t1.wifi_name = t2.wifi_name;
```

second query:

```
select t1.wifi_name, (t2.sconn*100)::numeric/t1.ttconn
from (select wifi_name, count(*) as ttconn 
      from conn_log 
      group by wifi_name) t1
join
     (select wifi_name, count(*) as sconn 
      from conn_log 
      where success = 1 
      group by wifi_name) t2
on t1.wifi_name = t2.wifi_name
```

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: @Colin'tHart: Amazon Redshift is fork based on  Postgres 8.0.2 and pretty limited in its capabilities: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for the difference between `INNER JOIN...ON` vs `WHERE` clause, there is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause). There are several answers there and the accepted answer pretty much summarises it all.

However, I cannot but comment that you query can be rewritten to significantly improve the performance, like this:

```
select wifi_name
      ,sum(case when success = 1 then 1 else 0 end)*100/count(*) as success_rate
from conn_log 
group by wifi_name;
```

In PostgreSQL 9.4+, it is even simpler:

```
select
    wifi_name, 
    count(*) filter (where success = 1) / count(*) * 100 as success_rate
from conn_log 
group by wifi_name;
```